# Wrong indexing of a string (Python)

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, indexing

Something that should be very simple and yet I am not able to solve it.
The indexing does not appear correctly when a character duplicates:
For example:

```py
list=[]
stringg="BAtmAn"
for i in stringg:
    if i.isupper():
        list.append(stringg.index(i))
print(list)
```

And the output shows `[0,1,1]` instead of `[0,1,4]`.
When the stringg variable is changed to `"BAtmEn"` it appears the way I expect it to appear in the first example.

Comment: `index` returns the index of the first match unless you provide a start.

Comment: I noticed, what should I write instead

Comment: Try using `enumerate` instead. Example `for index,letter in enumerate(stringg): if letter.isupper(): lst.append(index)`

Comment: Note: don't use `list` as a variable name as it will conflict with the built in `list` class.

Answer (score 1):

The following would do what you want

```py
stringg="BAtmAn"
print([x for x in range(len(stringg)) if stringg[x].isupper()])
print([i for i, c in enumerate(stringg) if c.isupper()])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list=[]
stringg="BAtmAn"
for i in range(len(stringg)):
    if stringg[i].isupper():
        list.append(i)
print(list)
```

should try this...
.index('item') can only find the index of the first of that 'item' in the list.